# Synthesis of Aristotle and Plato

Tags: aristotle, plato, greeks, neoplatonism, plotinus

I would like to know if there are any systematic and comprehensive texts on synthesising Aristotle and Plato (mainly that come from a Neoplatonism stand point since I know this joining of the two philosophers' systems was a major objective of the Neoplatonists). After searching for a while I couldn't find any texts that were dedicated entirely to this matter so I'm guessing the topic is just covered generally in neoplatonic works without explicit indication.

Answer (score 2):

*Aristotle and Other Platonists* by [Lloyd P. Gerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd_P._Gerson) is dedicated to this issue.

From the introduction:

> Aristotle versus Plato. For a long time that is the angle from which the
> tale has been told, in textbooks on the history of philosophy and to university students. Aristotle’s philosophy, so the story goes, was *au fond* in opposition to Plato’s. But it was not always thus.

> This book aims to give an account of how
> the perception of harmony arose among these Platonists, how it was articulated and defended, and to what extent it is justified.

Answer (score 1):

A good start is the entry [neoplatonism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/neoplatonism/) from Stanford Online encyclopedia. Here is a quote from its introduction:

> However, and more importantly, their [= the Neoplatonists’] signature
> project is more accurately described as a grand synthesis of an
> intellectual heritage that was by then exceedingly rich and profound.
> In effect, they absorbed, appropriated, and creatively harmonized
> almost the entire Hellenic tradition of philosophy, religion, and even
> literature—with the exceptions of Epicureanism, which they roundly
> rejected, and the thoroughgoing corporealism of the Stoics. […]

> The
> most fundamental of these assumptions, which the Neoplatonists shared
> with the majority of intellectuals of the ancient world, including
> most pre-Socratic thinkers as well as Socrates, Plato, Aristotle and
> their followers, is that mindful consciousness (nous, often translated
> as thought, intelligence, or intellect) is in an important sense
> ontologically prior to the physical realm typically taken for ultimate
> reality (Mind over Matter).

> There existed a dispute between Plato and
> Aristotle over whether or not the objects of mindful consciousness
> (abstract concepts, Platonic or otherwise, numbers, geometrical
> properties, and so forth) are also ontologically prior, but the
> Neoplatonists regarded this fact as a matter of inconsequential
> detail.

1. Hence the project of the Neoplatonists was the grand synthesis of
   the philosophical approaches of nearly all of their predecessors.

   Aristotle was a student of Plato. But Aristotle argues against the
   theory of forms, one of the main doctrines of his teacher, in
   Aristotle’s “Metaphysics, book I, Chap. 9”, see [Metaphysics](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0052%3Abook%3D1%3Asection%3D990b).
2. I cannot imagine how a synthesis of the two positions of Plato and
   Aristotle could look like. And I question that the proponents of
   such a synthesis did a careful reading of the original texts. We
   have their texts. Both philosophers belong to the most studied
   philosophers of all time.

Therefore: Who votes for an integration of the ideas of Plato and Aristotle should support his/her claim by pointing to specific texts of the two.